# Gauss-Jordan for similar equation systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm doing one exercise from a book, that asks to solve a couple of linear equations. The first one is
\begin{alignat}{3}
2x&-\phantom{0}y&+z&=\phantom{-}1 \\
-2x&+\phantom{0}y&-3z&=-5 \\
4x&-3y&+z&=\phantom{-}5 \\
\end{alignat}
The second one being very similar, except for the independent terms: 
\begin{alignat}{3}
2x&-\phantom{0}y&+z&=\phantom{-}1 \\
-2x&+\phantom{0}y&-3z&=-3 \\
4x&-3y&+z&=\phantom{-}1 
\end{alignat}

I have reduced the first system using Gauss-Jordan to the following matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{10}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, there's a note from the author that reads (translating as best as possible): "due to the fact that both systems are related, there's a simpler way to solve them without doing the entire procedure, can you spot it?"

Well I have been at this for hours and re-reading the chapter trying to find some theorem that I missed, to no avail. Does anyone know what is the author referring to?

Comment: I can see a way to solve the two systems without doing the entire procedure *twice*. Set up your augmented matrix with *two* extra columns, one for each set of independent terms. Alternatively, find the inverse of the coefficient matrix (doing Gauss-Jordan once) and then compute the product of the inverse with each vector of independent terms.

Comment: If you calculate the inverse, then you can use the inverse then you can use it for both systems, but its not much easier. I guess @GerryMyerson has a better idea,

Comment: @GerryMyerson I may argue that you have done the procedure twice: once for the first system, once for the two system putting together. Of course, I might think in the wrong way.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I like that idea of augmenting the matrix with two extra columns, perhaps that's what the author meant without having to go through the entire procedure twice. Thanks!